# Tensorflow variable_scope: tf.placeholder and tf.get_variable within a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, naming

I just tried to get an understanding of the TensorFlow naming behavior and I still need some clarification. 
I worked on a project where I went into trouble with the naming of tensor, because they were predefined in a function, which was called later.

So I have the following example here:

```
import tensorflow as tf


    def foo():

        with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):

            a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="a")
            b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="b")

        return a,b
    ##

    a,b  = foo()

    print(a)
    print(b)
```

I get the output:

```
Tensor("foo/a:0", dtype=float32)
Tensor("foo/b:0", dtype=float32)
```

When I call it again though, I get the output:

```
Tensor("foo_1/a:0", dtype=float32)
Tensor("foo_1/b:0", dtype=float32)
```

Why is this the case? I set reuse on true, so I expect the tensors to be in the same variable_scope "foo" again or that the program throws an error like "tensors already defined".

So, I tried a workaround with tf.get_variable:

```
    def foo():
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):

        a = tf.get_variable("v", [1])


    return a
##

a1 = foo()
print(a1)

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
#call tensors by name in tensorflow to avoid confusion with the naming
graph.get_tensor_by_name("foo/v:0")
```

Here, i get always the same output:

```
<tf.Variable 'foo/v:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot work with variables because you cannot define a dynamic shape for them. You need placeholders to define variable shapes.
Can someone explain me why the program continues to create new variable_scopes for placeholders but not when I call tf.get_variable() ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the reuse of a scope by adding a '/' after the name i.e.: `tf.variable_scope("foo/", reuse=True):`

However that won't solve your problem.

In the case of variables, calling `tf.Variable` will always create a new variable, whereas calling `tf.get_variable` will reuse it if it already exists.

But with Placeholders there is no `tf.get_placeholder`.

What you can do is define your placeholders outside of foo, only once, and get them by name using `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(name)` or directly using the python variable whenever you need them.

example with `get_tensor_by_name`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("scope"):
    tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="a")
    tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="b")

def foo():
    a = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("scope/a:0")
    b = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("scope/b:0")

    return a,b

a,b = foo()

print(a)
print(b)
```

Note that placeholders, unlike variables, do not maintain a state that can be reused or not. They are merely a "pointer" to a tensor which will be fed later. They should not be part of your model, but an input to it, so you should not be creating them several times anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case that you ran the code in a Jupyter notebook twice make sure that the notebook's kernel is not reusing the variables.

If you, instead, call the function `foo()` multiple times within the scope of the default graph you always get the same result:

```
def foo():
  with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="a")
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="b")
  return a,b

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  a,b  = foo()

  print(a) # gives variable name 'foo/a'
  print(b) # gives variable name 'foo/b'
```

But that is different from the use case, where the function is called repeatedly to create more placeholders.

```
c,d = foo()
```

In this case the answer above of `f4` is the recommended solution.